# How can I fix errors with .getTheme and .createTheme while generating slides using Google Slides in my code?

Tags: javascript

`    function createSlides() {
// Create a new Google Slides presentation
var presentation = SlidesApp.create("Customers' Shopping Preferences");
var slides = presentation.getSlides();

```
// Define the slide layout and design
var themeColors = SlidesApp.getThemeColors();
themeColors.setPrimaryColor("#ff5722"); // Customize the primary color as desired
presentation.setThemeColors(themeColors);
presentation.getFontCollection().setHeading1FontFamily(SlidesApp.FontFamily.ARIAL); 
// Customize the font family as desired

// Create and format slides

// Slide 1 - Title slide
var slide1 = slides[0];
slide1.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Japanese Customers' Shopping Preferences")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(36).setBold(true);
slide1.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "In-Store vs. Online")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24);

// Slide 2 - Overall Shopping Preference
var slide2 = slides[1];
slide2.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Overall Shopping Preference")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide2.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.T`your text`extBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 2")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);

// Slide 3 - In-Store Shopping
var slide3 = slides[2];
slide3.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "In-Store Shopping")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide3.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 3")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);

// Slide 4 - Online Shopping
var slide4 = slides[3];
slide4.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Online Shopping")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide4.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 4")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);

// Slide 5 - Factors Influencing Preferences
var slide5 = slides[4];
slide5.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Factors Influencing   Preferences")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide5.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 5")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);

// Slide 6 - Comparison and Insights
var slide6 = slides[5];
slide6.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Comparison and Insights")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide6.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 6")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);

// Slide 7 - Thank you slide
var slide7 = slides[6];
slide7.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 0, "Thank You")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true);
slide7.insertTextBox(SlidesApp.TextBoxAlignment.CENTER, 0, 1, "Content for slide 7")
   .getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(18);
```

}`

How can I fix the above code? What do I need to add?
Am I missing something (besides actual coding skills)?

Comment: What are the errors?